# Как по клику на кнопку скрывать блоки с такими же динамическими классами

Tags: jquery

Есть нопка с динамически генерируемым классом. По нажатию на которую другие блоки(в меню) с таким же динамическим классом должны сворачиваться либо раскрываться.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать обращение к этим блокам в меню при нажатии на кнопку (через JQuery)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
let classNameSelector = '.'+($(this).attr('class'));
$(classNameSelector).hide();
})
```